# Java - find matching pairs from list

Tags: java, sorting

**background:** 
I need to load test a process on a server that I am working with. What I am doing is I am creating a bunch of files on client side and will upload them to server. The server is monitoring for new files (in input dir, file names are unique) and once there is a new file it processes it, once done, it creates a response file with same name but different extension to output dir. If the processing fails, it puts the incoming file to error dir. I am using the [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to monitor the changes on server, which outputs:

```
10:48:47 /path/to/in/ CREATE ABCD.infile1
10:48:55 /path/to/out/ CREATE ABCD.outfile1
```

or

```
10:49:11 /path/to/in/ CREATE ASDF.infile1
10:49:19 /path/to/err/ CREATE ASDF.infile1
```

**problem:**
I need to parse the list of all results (planning to implement in java) like so, that I take the infile and match it with the same file name (either found in ERR or OUT), calculate the time taken and indicate weather it was success or not. The idea I am having is to create 3 lists (in, out, err) and try to parse, something like (in pseudo-code)

```
inList
outList
errList

for item : inList
   if outlist.contains(item) parse;
   else if errList.contains(item) parse;
   else error;
```

**question:**
Is this efficient? Or is there a better way to approach this situation? Anyway, you might think that it is a code you are executing just once, why the struggle, but I really would like to know how do handle this properly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with lists is problematic, as you will have to keep them synchronized properly with the state of drive and always load them. What is more you will reach at some point capacity limit for file stored in single location.

Alternatives what you have are that you use i/o API to check [path existence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), or introduce a between database where you will store your values.

Another approach is database where you will store the information about keys and physical paths that file really has.

If I was you i would start with the I/O API and design a simple interface that could be replaced in future if the solution would appear to be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "UserDefinedfileAttributeView" concept.
Create your own File attribute, say, "Result" and set its value accordingly for the files in IN dir. If the file is moved to OUT dir, "Result"="Success" and if the file is moved to ERR dir, "Result"="Error"
I tried the below code, hope it helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
    Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\rohit\\Desktop\\imp docs\\Steps.txt");
    UserDefinedFileAttributeView userView = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
    String attribName  = "RESULT";
    String attribValue = "SUCCESS";
    userView.write(attribName, Charset.defaultCharset().encode(attribValue));

    List<String> attribList = userView.list();
    for (String s : attribList) {            
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(userView.size(s));
        userView.read(s, buf);
        buf.flip();
        String value = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buf).toString();
        if("SUCCESS".equals(value)){
            System.out.print(String.format("User defined attribute: %s", s));
            System.out.println(String.format("; value: %s", value));
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
```

You can do this for every file placed in IN dir.